# crystal report generate error when try generate it

Tags: c#, timeout

Good Morning guys,

How do I increase the timeout to generate a report? when i try to generate as the select is very large, over time it's timeout error

ty for now

Answer (score 2):

You need to increase the timout on your connection string. It has nothing to do with your report. 
e.g. setting

> Connection Timeout=30

in connection string will set the timeout to 30 seconds.

Comment: is this correct?         
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 999999;

Comment: yes it is correct, but you should ideally save it in connection string. See here for details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx

Comment: In my server localhost it works, but the client generate this error below:
http://www.imagebam.com/image/12c543283278786

Comment: are you calling it over the webservice? If yes, change the timeout setting of webservice as well.